# How to get a google map to use 100% of its parent container?

Tags: javascript, css, api, google-maps

I have tried to do this in many different ways but the most obvious was this:

```
var map2 = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map2"), {size:"100%"});
```

That does not work.

Comment: This should happen automatically. There is probably something else interfering. Can you post some code, or a link?  By the way, the "size" element you're using there needs to be a GSize, which is created like this: var size = new GSize(500,400);

Comment: That is what I expected too. The solution bellow solved my problem by by an inline style on the div itself. Using GSize did not work because it would not take a percentage. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Google says](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/introduction.html):

> Unless you specify a size explicitly for the map using GMapOptions in the constructor, the    map implicitly uses the size of the container to size itself.

So set the size of your map container fill all available space:

```
<div id="map2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: You don't event need to add the width css property. Because "div" is naturally a block level element it will fill to it's parent's width :)

Good answer though!

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to use GSize which would not take a percentage.

Comment: added `position: relative;` with above and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about dynamically calculating the dimensions of it's parent container and explicitly setting them on the google map element? Assuming 100%/100% height don't work out.

Comment: I am doing that today using jQuery. It works for the most part but if the user resizes the window the map does not resize with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just specifying width:100%; height:100% wasn't enough for me...

But I got it working by using the following BODY code:

```
<body onload="initialize()" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
```

And using the following map code:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

See the result at http://arve.epfl.ch/test/

/shawn

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="some-pannel">
    <div class="map-wrapper">
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.some-pannel{
    position: relative;
    width: 123px;
    height 321px;  
}
.map-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```